# How do you greet multiple recipients in an e-mail?

Tags: email, greetings

How do you greet multiple recipients in an e-mail?

Assuming they're both male, I just use "Sirs", but it seems a bit informal.

Comment: I begin informal emails to multiple recipients with "Comrades". Maybe it's a Cold War nostalgia thing :-)

Comment: Haha.. I love using those for informal emails. this is in a professional context though. I'm gonna wait for a few more votes.  The answers vary from one end to another.

Comment: How about "Hi y'all!" or "Howdy folks!"? ;)

Comment: I use Sirs/Mesdames sometimes :)

Comment: Gentlemen is more appropriate than "Sirs".

Comment: I would sometimes start with "Hello everyone", "Gentlemen"; and if there are just two then I name them "Hello John, Jane". If one person is the main recipient and others are just there I write "Hello John, (FYI Jane, Joe)".

Comment: First of all, ask yourself whether you really want to address many recipients. You should generally only do that when you're sending to a mailing list, and in that case, there's really no point in addressing them all (if you send the mail using software you could insert the recipient's name). Otherwise, you should limit the people in the 'to' field to only those people you really expect an answer from, or reply to (other recipients should just be in CC). Then just use their names, e.g.:

John, could you have a look at the following?

Paul, Frank, you can stop investigating this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you don't know the recipients' names, I refer you to the other answers. However, if you *do* know their names, then I will add that I would actually just write:

> Dear John,
> Dear Jack,

I have been using this formula for more than a decade. So far, nobody has complained. For me, this approach has quite a few advantages. First of all, it is more personal than simply "Greetings" or "Hi all". Secondly, if one of those people is the main recipient and the other is CC, or if one of them has a higher rank (say, he is the boss of the other), I can reflect that in my address by mentioning him first. Lastly, this formula can be easily adapted to many situations. If some (or all) of the recipients are female I simply write:

> Dear John,
> Dear Jane,

If I need to make it more formal, I simply write:

> Dear Mr. Smith,
> Dear Ms. Black,

And I can easily extend it to three or even four people:

> Dear Mr. Smith,
> Dear Ms. Black,
> Dear Mr. Blunt,

Now, when I am addressing more than four people, I often *do* use something like "Greetings", "Hi everybody", "Dear clients", "Dear colleagues". However, even then I sometimes set the most important recipient apart by writing:

> Dear Prof. Black,
> Dear colleagues,

or

> Dear Mr. President,
> Dear Members of the Committee,

Answer (score 63):

If I am addressing a few people who are well known to me, I would generally use:

> Dear John, Bill, Jack,

If I am addressing a lot of people, or people who are not familiar to me, I would go with:

> Dear All,

Comment: I tend to go with this. Or I will just put the most important people in the "To:" heading, the others in "CC:" and not address them at all.

Comment: What rule do you base yourself on to capitalize 'All'?

Comment: @VincentSels maybe it looks cool? xD

Comment: Up Voting as I do the same.

Comment: @VincentSels The mythical All has been present in all technical discussion lists from before Usenet started. It went downhill from there.

Answer (score 31):

I rarely begin emails with a salutation. If I do, it is usually just the name - I have never transferred the pointless 'Dear' to emails.

If I wanted to put one in a group email, I suppose I would start with a word like "friends", or "people", or "folks", depending on the context and formality.

Comment: I don't care what got accepted, **this is the right answer**. Email is not a written letter. The (automatically generated) header is meant to take the place of most of that formal stuff you'd manually put at the top of a written letter. If I see a salutation on one, my spam filters go on high alert.

Comment: Agree, this should definitely be the accepted answer. "Dear" is nearly always omitted in emails, and salutations are frequently omitted as well.

Comment: The only time I ever include a greeting in an email is when it is being CC'd to a lot of people -- particularly bosses -- I will often greet the *primary* recipient in the email as a hint to other recipients.

Comment: I can't agree with this more. Dear is becoming outdated and should really only be used in written letters. I would be taken a back and a bit put off if I received a legitimate e-mail with "Dear" as the salutation.

Comment: @T.E.D. But isn't using "Dear" a sign of courtesy? A throw back to times when letters were written on paper and posted by hand.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, its a sign of ignorance of the accepted etiquette of email.

Comment: @T.E.D. That's a bit harsh :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA - In this day and age, anyone who doesn't take a harsh view of their incoming email had better have a really awesome anti-malware setup.

Comment: I think it should be noted that in some circles (notably academic circles), "Dear" is still very much expected.

Comment: @T.E.D. There are hundreds of "accepted" etiquettes of email.

Comment: @jinawee - I wrote this about a decade ago. I still stand by the statement that email is not a written letter, and should be treated as its own thing, but I'm too old these days to waste my energy railing against the oncoming tide. If anyone wants to put pointless nonsense in theirs, well there are worse things for society they could be spending that time on instead, so knock yourself out.

Answer (score 22):

It's kind of a carryover from my medievalist hobby, but I really like using

> Greetings,

or even

> Greetings!

for emails to a group of people. It's also really handy for addressing a single person when you're unsure of that person's gender and/or title.

Comment: This works very well if one or more of the recipient addresses does not belong to a single person

Answer (score 17):

If you are working together on a project, then I rather like

> Dear team

This can be appropriate even if the recipients include people from both your company and the client. It's a subtle reminder that you are all working towards a common goal.

More generally, I'd just use

> Dear all,

or just

> All,

Comment: Since you are referring to a specific team, or a specific set of people (implied by the To and Cc lists), I would capitalize 'Dear Team' and 'Dear All'.

Comment: @Jonathan I see no reason to capitalise team or all.

Comment: "Team" is always smarmy. Better to just say "People I don't actually respect or care about." or just say 'all'

Comment: I like 'Dear team' but would use 'Dear team members' myself.

Answer (score 9):

"Sirs" is just completely wrong.  If you are addressing more than one man, it would be "Gentlemen".

Comment: -1 "Sirs" or "Dear Sirs" was the traditional polite form of address when writing to a company rather than to an individual named person.  I don't see why it cannot continue to serve that purpose, even in e-mails, when writing to a company or organisation in general.

Answer (score 5):

Email is still sufficiently young that formal conventions have not emerged.
I find it useful to imagine myself in the mind of the recipient and ask what information I need to give them in the greeting.

If the email is really to be sent with equal priority to a number of recipients and they regard themselves as part of a group (fellow developers for example), then I would use

> Dear All,

If, actually, the email is a mailshot to a number of individuals who don't know each other, then its an individual email.

> Dear Sir,

or possibly

> Dear Sir (or Madam),

Here, I prefer to use the convention that *Sir* is neuter.

And lastly, if an email is really to a single individual, but with a few more individuals copied in (such as a question to an individual developer, but where I want the email trail to be visible to the group), then I would use

> Dear Bob (Alice, Charlie, Dilbert)

The last one is not a convention I have seen elsewhere, but I find it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using, "Hello to all".  It seems to work well for both male and female recipients and is formal enough to use in a business setting.

Comment: It strikes me as grossly informal (altho' that may vary between cultures & countries - I'm writing from the UK).

Answer (score 3):

If it is a formal letter, then you can use 'Dear Sirs' but if it is informal, simply 'Hi' is fine. 'Hi' addresses either one person or many, the same as 'you' refers to one person or many.  I would not ever use 'Gentlemen', but I am from Australia where our English is more informal.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use the words

Hi All,

Comment: Locate the comma after "HI," and use a lower-case letter for "all."

It should be 
Hi, all ~

Comment: @Ann, We don't do that when writing emails even though it's grammatically correct.

Comment: I don't know who "we" refers to, but "Hi All" is never correct on two counts. 
In the eyes of the people who know better, writing this must necessarily reflect negatively on you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *gents* to refer to many recipients.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this should be used in a formal e-mail, but +1 because it sounds classy.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with louiser89 and I will add that - even though many people or perhaps most people don't think that "Dear" is appropriate on emails - I will continue to use "Dear" or, in my language, "Caro (Cara)". It is not only because we have always used it in letters and in commercial correspondence; it is not just traditions. "Dear" is a nice word, it is gentle and polite. It is not a word that could ever offend anybody. And it is certainly not formal, unless you consider formal the people you love or that you consider your friends, or the people you like. So why not use it also in emails? How can something nice become formal or old fashioned or, worse, strongly disliked? Of course we should never consider it obligatory, but why be against it? 
Dear Friends, don't be too angry with me: English is not my language, but it is a very "dear" language to me for many reasons.