# What style should I use in e-mail salutations to superiors, colleagues, or juniors?

Tags: email, salutations

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Salutation in an Email](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292/salutation-in-an-email)
>   [How do you greet multiple recipients in an e-mail?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-do-you-greet-multiple-recipients-in-an-e-mail)

How do I use the initial words while writing an e-mail, in particular, to my superiors?

Suppose somebody is writing a letter to the HR representative of a company, requesting a letter, approval, information, etc. Should the salutation be written like:

> Hi

or:

> Dear

or her/his name:

> Dear Jenny

Are any of these proper way? Or, should I leave it blank and start with the crux of the matter right away?

Does it matter whether I know the person or not, or if the person is not my superior but is a colleague or junior?

Comment: yes but that question refers to a group of people

Comment: Hello and welcome, @munish. I've made some (rather substantial) edits to help format your question and include your updated information in the title. You can edit further or revert if I accidentally changed your meaning! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally do a greeting (Good morning/afternoon) versus dear or hi, and feel this is more appropiate than dear or hi. Normally all my emails start as follows: 
Good morning/afternoon [First Name or Mr/Ms Last Name],
Hope all is well. [Start email]
I feel this is friendly and respectful to the recipient, and you would choose which titles to use depending on the relationship.

Comment: I agree with your choice for a saluation.  But unless it is a more formal request or a "Speech to group" type of email I would treat it like a memo.  The To and CC lines cover the saluation.