# Greeting for Correspondence to Multiple People

Tags: greetings, correspondence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you greet multiple recipients in an e-mail?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-do-you-greet-multiple-recipients-in-an-e-mail)

I'm sending an email to four people at a client, all in different roles / departments and of varying genders (*Dear Sirs* is out and probably not preferable to begin with). What greetings would be suitable?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these:

Greetings.

Hello.

Dear members of X team (if this is, say, different people working on the same project).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your relationship with them is. 'Dear Colleagues' might be appropriate in some cases, but perhaps not in this one. 'Dear Associates' might be another possibility. Or 'Dear Friends'?

Comment: I'm not sure that any of those apply. Colleagues or Associates seems to apply to those in the same field or the same company. Dear Friends is just not applicable.